# gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody>() vs. gameObject.rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are two ways to access RigidBody Component in gameObject:

- `gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody>()`
- `gameObject.rigidbody` (read only)

I would like to understand the reason for the (a bit redundant) read-only one in the light of the fact that there are no read-only properties for other Components like BoxCollider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gameObject.rigidbody` used in older version of unity but it has been depreciated from Unity 5.4.1p3. You need to use `this.gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody>();` in order to access 'rigidbody' in new versions, both method is used to get 'rigidbody' and apply Physics calculations via script there is no difference.

Comment: Is there any note about this in some reference? Is it just "obsolete" or "deprecated"?

Comment: you can check online documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject-rigidbody.html)

Answer (score 0):

`gameObject.rigidbody` was used in older versions of Unity. This way of getting a reference to a component attached to a GameObject is considered obsolete since it is counter-intuitive

Using `gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` is considered good practice as of writing.

Comment: It's not only a matter of good practice .. afaik it was actually removed.. at least that's what the API says

Comment: For more info : [Unity 5: API changes & automatic script updating](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/23/unity5-api-changes-automatic-script-updating/)

Comment: As of the current LTS Release 2019.1.0f1 this is still possible but deprecated @derHugo

Comment: I only saw [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject-rigidbody.html) `Removed in version 5.4.1p3
Property rigidbody has been deprecated. Use GetComponent<Rigidbody>() instead. (UnityUpgradable)` . And please note that the current LTS release is `2019.4` (it's always the `.4`) and [there](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-rigidbody.html) it also says `Removed` ;)

Comment: Oh. Sry. I think that was a mistake on my side. Of course I meant 2019.4.1f1